# checking if variable used in blade (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to optimize code of ecommerce project. So I want to check if variable used in blade. with laravel profler I can count query count and view count. But can not check if variable used? Now I have to do it manually and it takes a lot time.

Comment: Please, add some code showing your attempts.

Comment: Please, have a look at this [How to Ask](https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow)

Comment: example: at home page I have more details and so more views. and I past 20 variable.

Comment: you can use `@if ` for checking something in blade or  `@php`  for add php code to blade